# Anaconda Navigator not opening on M2 MacBook Air running MacOS Ventura

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, anaconda, crash

I just downloaded anaconda on my M2 MacBook Air running MacOS Ventura (version 13.2.1). The download process went smoothly and I was able to locate Anaconda Navigator. But when I try opening it, it just won’t open without even showing any error message.

After trying to run it from the terminal using anaconda-navigator, I got the following error:

[image: Error message showing in the terminal]

**Note that I have python 3.9.13 which was downloaded with anaconda when I downloaded it.**

I tried to uninstall and reinstall anaconda, I also tried to check the .condarc file I also tried to check the list of packages that were installed using conda list to make sure that anaconda-navigator was there (Version 2.3.1 was installed). I also tried to uninstall and reinstall anaconda navigator using conda remove anaconda-navigator & conda install anaconda-navigator but none of these worked. Is there anyone else experiencing. the same issue? Or does anyone know how to fix that?

I will include the list of packages that were also installed out of the box for your reference:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py39hecd8cb5_1
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda                  2022.10                  py39_0
anaconda-client           1.11.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
anaconda-navigator        2.3.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
anaconda-project          0.11.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
anyio                     3.5.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
applaunchservices         0.3.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
appnope                   0.1.2           py39hecd8cb5_1001
appscript                 1.1.2            py39h9ed2024_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39hca72f7f_0
arrow                     1.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
astroid                   2.11.7           py39hecd8cb5_0
astropy                   5.1              py39h67323c0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
automat                   20.2.0                     py_0
autopep8                  1.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.2.0            py39hca72f7f_1
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
bitarray                  2.5.1            py39hca72f7f_0
bkcharts                  0.2              py39hecd8cb5_1
black                     22.6.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blosc                     1.21.0               h8346a28_1
bokeh                     2.4.3            py39hecd8cb5_0
boto3                     1.24.28          py39hecd8cb5_0
botocore                  1.27.28          py39hecd8cb5_0
bottleneck                1.3.5            py39h67323c0_0
brotli                    1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
brotli-bin                1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h9ed2024_1003
brunsli                   0.1                  h23ab428_0
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0
c-ares                    1.18.1               hca72f7f_0
ca-certificates           2022.07.19           hecd8cb5_0
cctools                   949.0.1             h9abeeb2_25
cctools_osx-64            949.0.1             hc7db93f_25
certifi                   2022.9.24        py39hecd8cb5_0
cffi                      1.15.1           py39hc55c11b_0
cfitsio                   3.470                hbd21bf8_7
chardet                   4.0.0           py39hecd8cb5_1003
charls                    2.2.0                h23ab428_0
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.0.4            py39hecd8cb5_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
clyent                    1.2.2            py39hecd8cb5_1
colorama                  0.4.5            py39hecd8cb5_0
colorcet                  3.0.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
conda                     22.9.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
conda-build               3.22.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
conda-content-trust       0.1.3            py39hecd8cb5_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling    1.9.0            py39hca72f7f_0
conda-repo-cli            1.0.20           py39hecd8cb5_0
conda-token               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
constantly                15.1.0             pyh2b92418_0
cookiecutter              1.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              37.0.1           py39hf6deb26_0
cssselect                 1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
curl                      7.84.0               hca72f7f_0
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
cython                    0.29.32          py39he9d5cce_0
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py39h9ed2024_0
daal4py                   2021.6.0         py39h01d92e1_1
dal                       2021.6.0           haf03e11_929
dask                      2022.7.0         py39hecd8cb5_0
dask-core                 2022.7.0         py39hecd8cb5_0
dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7
datashader                0.14.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
datashape                 0.5.4            py39hecd8cb5_1
debugpy                   1.5.1            py39he9d5cce_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill                      0.3.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
distributed               2022.7.0         py39hecd8cb5_0
docutils                  0.18.1           py39hecd8cb5_3
entrypoints               0.4              py39hecd8cb5_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
fftw                      3.3.9                h9ed2024_1
filelock                  3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flake8                    4.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
flask                     1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.11.0               hd8bbffd_0
fsspec                    2022.7.1         py39hecd8cb5_0
future                    0.18.2           py39hecd8cb5_1
gensim                    4.1.2            py39he9d5cce_0
gettext                   0.21.0               h7535e17_0
giflib                    5.2.1                haf1e3a3_0
glib                      2.69.1               h8346a28_1
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
gmp                       6.2.1                he9d5cce_3
gmpy2                     2.1.2            py39hd5de756_0
greenlet                  1.1.1            py39h23ab428_0
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               h4180768_2
gstreamer                 1.14.0               h0fc69c2_2
h5py                      3.7.0            py39h4a1dd59_0
hdf5                      1.10.6               h10fe05b_1
heapdict                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
holoviews                 1.15.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
hvplot                    0.8.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
hyperlink                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
icu                       58.2                 h0a44026_3
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagecodecs               2021.8.26        py39h0f85e6e_1
imageio                   2.19.3           py39hecd8cb5_0
imagesize                 1.4.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
importlib-metadata        4.11.3           py39hecd8cb5_0
importlib_metadata        4.11.3               hd3eb1b0_0
incremental               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intake                    0.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          hecd8cb5_3538
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.15.2           py39hecd8cb5_0
ipython                   7.31.1           py39hecd8cb5_1
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemadapter               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemloaders               1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
itsdangerous              2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jdcal                     1.4.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.18.1           py39hecd8cb5_1
jellyfish                 0.9.0            py39hca72f7f_0
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
jmespath                  0.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9e                   hca72f7f_0
jq                        1.6               h9ed2024_1000
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                4.16.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
jupyter                   1.0.0            py39hecd8cb5_8
jupyter_client            7.3.4            py39hecd8cb5_0
jupyter_console           6.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.11.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
jupyter_server            1.18.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
jupyterlab                3.4.4            py39hecd8cb5_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.10.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jxrlib                    1.1                  haf1e3a3_2
keyring                   23.4.0           py39hecd8cb5_0
kiwisolver                1.4.2            py39he9d5cce_0
krb5                      1.19.2               hcd88c3b_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py39h9ed2024_0
lcms2                     2.12                 hf1fd2bf_0
ld64                      530                 h20443b4_25
ld64_osx-64               530                 h70f3046_25
ldid                      2.1.2                h2d21305_2
lerc                      3.0                  he9d5cce_0
libaec                    1.0.4                hb1e8313_1
libarchive                3.6.1                he336d3b_0
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                hca72f7f_7
libclang                  12.0.0          default_hbc2896b_2
libcurl                   7.84.0               h6dfd666_0
libcxx                    14.0.6               h9765a3e_0
libdeflate                1.8                  h9ed2024_5
libedit                   3.1.20210910         hca72f7f_0
libev                     4.33                 h9ed2024_1
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_2_0_h246ff09_26
libgfortran5              11.2.0              h246ff09_26
libiconv                  1.16                 hca72f7f_2
libidn2                   2.3.2                h9ed2024_0
liblief                   0.11.5               he9d5cce_1
libllvm11                 11.1.0               h46f1229_5
libllvm12                 12.0.0               h9b2ccf5_3
libllvm14                 14.0.6               he552d86_0
libnghttp2                1.46.0               ha29bfda_0
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0
libpq                     12.9                 h1c9f633_3
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h23ab428_0
libssh2                   1.10.0               h0a4fc7d_0
libtiff                   4.4.0                h2ef1027_0
libunistring              0.9.10               h9ed2024_0
libwebp                   1.2.2                h56c3ce4_0
libwebp-base              1.2.2                hca72f7f_0
libxml2                   2.9.14               hbf8cd5e_0
libxslt                   1.1.35               h5b33f42_0
libzopfli                 1.0.3                hb1e8313_0
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               h0dcd299_0
llvmlite                  0.38.0           py39h8346a28_0
locket                    1.0.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
lxml                      4.9.1            py39h65b224f_0
lz4                       3.1.3            py39h9ed2024_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h23ab428_1
lzo                       2.10                 haf1e3a3_2
markdown                  3.3.4            py39hecd8cb5_0
markupsafe                2.0.1            py39h9ed2024_0
matplotlib                3.5.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
matplotlib-base           3.5.2            py39hfb0c5b7_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6            py39hecd8cb5_0
mccabe                    0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h9ed2024_1000
mkl                       2021.4.0           hecd8cb5_637
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h9ed2024_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h4ab4a9b_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hb2f4e1b_0
mock                      4.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1
mpfr                      4.0.2                h9066e36_1
mpi                       1.0                       mpich
mpich                     3.3.2                external_0
mpmath                    1.2.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
msgpack-python            1.0.3            py39haf03e11_0
multipledispatch          0.6.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
mypy_extensions           0.4.3            py39hecd8cb5_1
navigator-updater         0.3.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
nbclassic                 0.3.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient                  0.5.13           py39hecd8cb5_0
nbconvert                 6.4.4            py39hecd8cb5_0
nbformat                  5.5.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
ncurses                   6.3                  hca72f7f_3
nest-asyncio              1.5.5            py39hecd8cb5_0
networkx                  2.8.4            py39hecd8cb5_0
nltk                      3.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
nose                      1.3.7           pyhd3eb1b0_1008
notebook                  6.4.12           py39hecd8cb5_0
nspr                      4.33                 he9d5cce_0
nss                       3.74                 h47edf6a_0
numba                     0.55.1           py39hae1ba45_0
numexpr                   2.8.3            py39h2e5f0a9_0
numpy                     1.21.5           py39h2e5f0a9_3
numpy-base                1.21.5           py39h3b1a694_3
numpydoc                  1.4.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0
oniguruma                 6.9.7.1              h9ed2024_0
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h66ea3da_0
openpyxl                  3.0.10           py39hca72f7f_0
openssl                   1.1.1q               hca72f7f_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.4            py39he9d5cce_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
panel                     0.13.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
param                     1.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
parsel                    1.6.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
patch                     2.7.6             h1de35cc_1001
pathlib                   1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
pathspec                  0.9.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
patsy                     0.5.2            py39hecd8cb5_1
pcre                      8.45                 h23ab428_0
pep8                      1.7.1            py39hecd8cb5_1
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    9.2.0            py39hde71d04_1
pip                       22.2.2           py39hecd8cb5_0
pkginfo                   1.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
platformdirs              2.5.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
plotly                    5.9.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
pluggy                    1.0.0            py39hecd8cb5_1
ply                       3.11             py39hecd8cb5_0
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prometheus_client         0.14.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0
protego                   0.1.16                     py_0
psutil                    5.9.0            py39hca72f7f_0
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
py                        1.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-lief                   0.11.5           py39he9d5cce_1
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycodestyle               2.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py39h9ed2024_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyct                      0.4.8            py39hecd8cb5_1
pycurl                    7.45.1           py39h0a4fc7d_0
pydispatcher              2.0.5            py39hecd8cb5_2
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyerfa                    2.0.0            py39h9ed2024_0
pyflakes                  2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyhamcrest                2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pyjwt                     2.4.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
pylint                    2.14.5           py39hecd8cb5_0
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyobjc-core               8.5              py39hc55c11b_0
pyobjc-framework-cocoa    8.5              py39hca72f7f_0
pyobjc-framework-coreservices 8.5              py39hca72f7f_0
pyobjc-framework-fsevents 8.5              py39hecd8cb5_0
pyodbc                    4.0.34           py39he9d5cce_0
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9            py39hecd8cb5_0
pyqt                      5.15.7           py39he9d5cce_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py39he9d5cce_0
pyqtwebengine             5.15.7           py39he9d5cce_0
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py39hca72f7f_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
pytables                  3.6.1            py39h648f197_1
pytest                    7.1.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
python                    3.9.13               hdfd78df_1
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2           py39hecd8cb5_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-lsp-black          1.2.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server         1.5.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-snappy             0.6.0            py39h23ab428_3
python.app                3                py39hca72f7f_0
pytz                      2022.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
pyviz_comms               2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywavelets                1.3.0            py39hca72f7f_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py39hca72f7f_1
pyzmq                     23.2.0           py39he9d5cce_0
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt                        5.15.9               hecd8cb5_0
qt-main                   5.15.2               h719ae48_7
qt-webengine              5.15.9               h90a370e_4
qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.3.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
qtpy                      2.2.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
qtwebkit                  5.212                h24dc246_4
queuelib                  1.5.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
readline                  8.1.2                hca72f7f_1
regex                     2022.7.9         py39hca72f7f_0
requests                  2.28.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
requests-file             1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ripgrep                   13.0.0               hc2228c6_0
rope                      0.22.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rtree                     0.9.7            py39hecd8cb5_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py39h9ed2024_0
s3transfer                0.6.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
scikit-image              0.19.2           py39hae1ba45_0
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py39hae1ba45_1
scikit-learn-intelex      2021.6.0         py39hecd8cb5_0
scipy                     1.9.1            py39h3d31255_0
scrapy                    2.6.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
seaborn                   0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
service_identity          18.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                63.4.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
sip                       6.6.2            py39he9d5cce_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
smart_open                5.2.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
snappy                    1.1.9                he9d5cce_0
sniffio                   1.2.0            py39hecd8cb5_1
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcollections         2.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    5.0.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    5.3.3            py39hecd8cb5_0
spyder-kernels            2.3.3            py39hecd8cb5_0
sqlalchemy                1.4.39           py39hca72f7f_0
sqlite                    3.39.3               h707629a_0
statsmodels               0.13.2           py39hca72f7f_0
sympy                     1.10.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
tabulate                  0.8.10           py39hecd8cb5_0
tapi                      1000.10.8            ha1b3eb9_0
tbb                       2021.6.0             haf03e11_0
tbb4py                    2021.6.0         py39haf03e11_0
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tenacity                  8.0.1            py39hecd8cb5_1
terminado                 0.13.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
testpath                  0.6.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tifffile                  2021.7.2           pyhd3eb1b0_2
tinycss                   0.4             pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0
tldextract                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1            py39hecd8cb5_0
tomlkit                   0.11.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
toolz                     0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py39h9ed2024_0
tqdm                      4.64.1           py39hecd8cb5_0
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
twisted                   22.2.0           py39hca72f7f_1
typing-extensions         4.3.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
typing_extensions         4.3.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
tzdata                    2022c                h04d1e81_0
ujson                     5.4.0            py39he9d5cce_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
unixodbc                  2.3.11               hb456775_0
urllib3                   1.26.11          py39hecd8cb5_0
w3lib                     1.21.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
watchdog                  2.1.6            py39h999c104_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py39hecd8cb5_1
websocket-client          0.58.0           py39hecd8cb5_4
werkzeug                  2.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wget                      1.21.3               h6dfd666_0
whatthepatch              1.0.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
wrapt                     1.14.1           py39hca72f7f_0
wurlitzer                 3.0.2            py39hecd8cb5_0
xarray                    0.20.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
xlrd                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlsxwriter                3.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlwings                   0.27.15          py39hecd8cb5_0
xz                        5.2.6                hca72f7f_0
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h23ab428_0
zfp                       0.5.5                he9d5cce_6
zict                      2.1.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
zipp                      3.8.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
zlib                      1.2.12               h4dc903c_3
zope                      1.0              py39hecd8cb5_1
zope.interface            5.4.0            py39h9ed2024_0
zstd                      1.5.2                hcb37349_0
```

In addition, I tried resetting anaconda navigator through the terminal but I got the same error message.

Any help would be of great value :)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got off a phone call with an Anaconda representative to try to solve this issue and it seems like they do not have any current support for M2 Macs and told me that I had to settle with using anaconda through the terminal until they do support this new chip.

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to successfully download and install the latest Anaconda distribution on my Mac M2 (running 13.4.1).  It doesn't install Anaconda Navigator in the Applications folder but rather just an alias that links to the app.

The actual application is in:
/Users/[COMPUTER NAME]/anaconda3/Anaconda-Navigator.app